# dask df.col.unique() vs df.col.drop_duplicates()

Tags: dask

In dask what is the difference between

```
df.col.unique()
```

and

```
df.col.drop_duplicates()
```

Both return a series containing the unique elements of `df.col`.
There is a difference in the index, `unique` result is indexed by 1..N while `drop_duplicates` indexed by an arbitrary looking sequence of numbers.

What is the significance of the index returned by `drop_duplicates`?

Is there any reason to use one over the other if the index is not important?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Dask.dataframe has both because Pandas has both, and dask.dataframe mostly copies the Pandas API.  Unique is a holdover from Pandas' history with Numpy.

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, 2, 1], 'y': [1., 2., 3.]}, index=pd.Index(['a', 'b', 'A'], name='I'))

In [3]: df.x.drop_duplicates()
Out[3]: 
I
a    1
b    2
Name: x, dtype: int64

In [4]: df.x.unique()
Out[4]: array([1, 2])
```

In dask.dataframe we deviate slightly and choose to use a `dask.dataframe.Series` rather than a `dask.array.Array` because one can't precompute the length of the array and so can't act lazily.

In practice there is little reason to use `unique` over `drop_duplicates`

Comment: One reason to use `unique` is that it returns a `numpy.ndarray` instead of a pandas Series.